# struct.pack longer than its parts?

Tags: python, binary, pack

I want to unpack 6 values: 2 * `UInt16`, 1 * `UInt32`, 1 * `UInt16`, 2 * `Int64`

Adding the size in bytes up, I get 26.

But python seems to think it should be 32:

```
>>> a = struct.pack("H",0)
>>> len(a)
2 <-- correct
>>> a = struct.pack("L",0)
>>> len(a)
4 <-- correct
>>> a = struct.pack("q",0)
>>> len(a)
8 <-- correct
>>> a = struct.pack("HHLHqq",0,0,0,0,0,0)
>>> len(a)
32 < -- should be 2 + 2 + 4 + 2 + 8 + 8 = 26 
>>> a = struct.pack("HHLHq",0,0,0,0,0)
>>> len(a)
24 < -- should be 2 + 2 + 4 + 2 + 8 = 18
>>> a = struct.pack("HHLH",0,0,0,0)
>>> len(a)
10 <-- correct again
```

`struct.unpack` has the same problem and requires 32 byte to unpack "HHLHqq". However, in my application the data gets send from an external source and it's just 26 bytes.

I could unpack it one by one as a workaround, but there must be a way to disable this padding for sure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to: https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html

> No padding is added when using non-native size and alignment, e.g. with ‘<’, ‘>’, ‘=’, and ‘!’.

So you have to just specify the endianness and the padding will be gone:

```
>>> import struct
>>> len(struct.pack("HHLHqq",0,0,0,0,0,0))
40
>>> len(struct.pack("<HHLHqq",0,0,0,0,0,0))
26
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps.
But why is padding added when not specifing an endianness? The docs also say that for AMD64 (which I am using) the default should be little endian already.

Comment: @user3696412 it does not matter, what endianness your processor is using. python works differently if you specify it explicitly or not.